# How to disable CORS in chrome to work with localhost and third party url on window 11 Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, version, same-origin-policy, disable

I want to access https://third-party-url/ from my localhost But chrome is throwing cors error
I am using window 11 and chrome version : Version 106.0.5249.103 which is latest version till 2022-10-10

Comment: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Answer (score 5):

Run cmd from Chrome's path.

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

This command is only disable cors in the window that opens after running the command. If you close this window, you can use the same command again.

Comment: Not working still showing cors issue

Comment: I think you should also close all running chrome instances before running this comnand, otherwise it may ignore the flags and just open new subprocess of existing chrome.